# How to add translate/rotate/scale tool to my threejs scene?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I recently tried out [THREE.js editor](http://threejs.org/editor/). If you click on an object,  translate/rotate/scale tools will show up in the scene, using which you can change the object's position/rotation/size. I tried to figure it out how the code works, but the only thing I've found is EditorControls, which controls just the camera.

[image: controls]

How is it possible to use this tools in my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its called `Transform controls`:

Example: http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_transform.html

```
control = new THREE.TransformControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
control.addEventListener( 'change', render );

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( mesh );

control.attach( mesh );
scene.add( control );
```